# Google Places API: error while autocompleting: NETWORK_ERROR

Tags: java, android-studio, google-places-api

I searched around to find the way to solve my problem, but nothing succeeded. I have already set up the billing account and got my api key. Here is my code (same as the tutorial and I only want the auto-complete function):

```
String apiKey = getString(R.string.api_key);
Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), apiKey);
AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
    // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
         Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
    // TODO: Handle the error.
         Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
    }
});
```

I also add permissions in my AndroidManifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

edit:
When I changed the places library version from 2.0.0 to 2.1.0, it shows no error but still cannot load search result. Anyone can help?

edit:
This is my app-level build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "###"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0'
}
```

When I implemented 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0', I got:

```
W/ui.finalprojec: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/ui.finalprojec: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/ui.finalprojec: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
```

When I implemented 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0', I got:

```
W/ui.finalprojec: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->objectFieldOffset(Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ui.finalprojec: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/ui.finalprojec: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/ui.finalprojec: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->allocateInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/ui.finalprojec: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->arrayBaseOffset(Ljava/lang/Class;)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->arrayIndexScale(Ljava/lang/Class;)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/ui.finalprojec: Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekLong(JZ)J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ui.finalprojec: Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeLong(JJZ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeInt(JIZ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekInt(JZ)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeByte(JB)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekByte(J)B (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->pokeByteArray(J[BII)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Llibcore/io/Memory;->peekByteArray(J[BII)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/ui.finalprojec: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/ui.finalprojec: Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ui.finalprojec: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
E/Places: Error while autocompleting: NETWORK_ERROR
W/ui.finalprojec: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
E/Places: Error while autocompleting: NETWORK_ERROR
E/Places: Error while autocompleting: NETWORK_ERROR
```

Also, I tried it in another computer, which gave me the same problem.

Comment: Do you still have this issue? If so, first of all, make sure that Places API is enabled on your project, that your API key is properly restricted and that your billing account is in good standing.

Comment: Secondly, please post your full logcat and manifest, and also your app-level build.gradle so that we're able to reproduce this issue from our side. Does this happen across multiple emulators/devices?

Comment: I have already updated my question. Any help would appreciate!

Comment: Thanks! Okay so there's nothing wrong with your code as far as I can see. Can you try something: create a brand new project to use Places SDK Autocomplete widget and follow all the exact steps from google's guide [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete). Set your own API key. Does the app run? Do you get the same/different error? And please share the emulator/device you're running it on.

Comment: Did you find any solution for that?

Comment: Regarding those warnings, check out my comment in this thread... It seems to be a problem inside Google's own libraries:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27095#issuecomment-643688238
I don't think they are preventing any functionality though.

Comment: In my case, in Android Studio I got these errors when trying to launch a new session when a previously started 'Profiling' session is still active. After terminating the profiling session I was able to start new session without any issues.